# Keep getting 'None' values for Class methods, and I don't understand why?

Tags: python, class, oop

tl;dr I have to go and sort out a bunch of xls workbooks which come with multitudes of variances in how they are formatted. I'm trying to make it as flexible as possible. It is reading my file, and when I print the method I get a value indicating something is stored in memory (a None value, unfortunately).

I set up a basic class to run inside a script depending on which one of the formats the spreadsheet comes in (pretty much a choice of 3). I can't simply change them to CSVs because I need to get into the sheets.

```py
class parse_class:

    def __init__(self, wb):
        self.wb = wb
        self.method1 = None
        self.method2 = None
        #and so on

    def method1(self):
        try:
            method_var = self.wb.sheet_by_name('sheet 1 name')
            self.method1 = method_var
        except:
            pass

    #and so on for the other methods in the class
```

I'm intending to pass these methods into various functions outside the class to extract values I need. Unfortunately, with a NoneType value, there isn't much I can extract. Am I setting up something wrong with my class?

(As far as why I am using try/excepts, the sheets may or may not exist in a given workbook, but use the same naming convention, if they exist)

Comment: Your method and instance variable names shadow each other. Try to avoid that

Comment: Don't do `self.method1 = None`. You're overriding the defs underneath when creating an object

Comment: So what is the code that is unexpectedly returning `None`?

Comment: Also, the method needs to explicitly return a value, otherwise it will default to returning `None`. So you must do something like `return self.wb.sheet_by_name('sheet 1 name')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted to set the default value to `None` and not to override them.

```
class parse_class:

    def __init__(self, wb):
        self.wb = wb

    def method1(self):
        try:
            method_var = self.wb.sheet_by_name('sheet 1 name')
            self.method1 = method_var
        except:
            pass
```

otherwise whatever you pass to your class it is still initialized to `None`.

Comment: This is totally wrong. You have overwritten `self.method1` with `None`, which will cause a TypeError when you try to call it.

Comment: @ekhumoro I have overwritten `self.method1` with `method1` in case he does not provide anything I don't know how he wants to handle this so I put `None` that's up to him.

Comment: @ekhumoro is that better? To not initialize them at all on class initialization?